# how to create laravel 6 pivot table with multi-word

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, database-migration, database-relations

I have Accounts table and Site_links table. When I use this code in Account Model:

```
public function site_links(){
    return $this->belongsToMany($SitelinkModel, 'account_site_link', 'account_id', 'site_link_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The values ​​of the two IDs are reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, so the problem is

the belonsToMany parameters must be like this (Model, id_num_of_this_table, id_num_of_the_other_table);

sample in my account model

```
public function site_links(){
    return $this->belongsToMany($SitelinkModel, 'account_site_link', 'site_link_id', 'account_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```